# How to create TLS load balancer service in K8s on Openstack

Tags: kubernetes, ssl-certificate, openstack

We are using openstack. I deployed nginx service first on port 80 using below yaml, and my application was working fine with http url.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  namespace: app1
  labels:
    io.kompose.service: nginx
  name: nginx
spec:
  ports:
    - name: "http"
      port: 80
      targetPort: 80
    - name: "30443"
      port: 30443
      targetPort: 30443
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    io.kompose.service: nginx
```

Then I edited my service.yaml and updated with SSL port 443 to enable https on my webpage:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  namespace: app1
  labels:
    io.kompose.service: nginx
  name: nginx
spec:
  ports:
    - name: "https"
      port: 443
      targetPort: 31303
    - name: "30443"
      port: 30443
      targetPort: 30443
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    io.kompose.service: nginx
```

Now I am little confused if I am enabling SSL the right way, also where should I place certificates/key. In my nginx.conf, below is the code I have placed:-

```
upstream xyzserver {
     server xyz.app1.svc.cluster.local:40002;
 }
 server {
     listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
     listen 443 ssl http2;
     client_max_body_size 200M;
     access_log /var/log/nginx/xyz_access.log;
     error_log /var/log/nginx/xyz_error.log;
#     ssl_certificate <cert-path>;
#     ssl_certificate_key <key-path>;
     proxy_read_timeout 720s;
     proxy_connect_timeout 720s;
     proxy_send_timeout 720s;
     proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
     proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
     proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
     proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
     location / {
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        rewrite ^/(.*)$ https://xyz.net.abc.com/$1 redirect;
        error_page 502 /Maintenance.html;
        location = /Maintenance.html {
                root /opt/nginx/nginx-1.20.1/html/;
                internal;
        }
     }
     gzip_types text/css text/less text/plain text/xml application/xml application/json application/javascript;
     gzip on;
 }
 server {
     listen [::]:80;
     listen 80;
     client_max_body_size 200M;
     access_log /var/log/nginx/xyz_access.log;
     error_log /var/log/nginx/xyz_error.log;

     proxy_read_timeout 720s;
     proxy_connect_timeout 720s;
     proxy_send_timeout 720s;
     proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
     proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
     proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
     proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;

     location / {
        proxy_buffering off;
        proxy_pass http://xyz.app1.svc.cluster.local:40002;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header referer "http://xyz.net.abc.com";
     }

     gzip_types text/css text/less text/plain text/xml application/xml application/json application/javascript;
     gzip on;
 }
```

Please help to guide.

Comment: Is your issue resolved? Try this [doc](https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/9419/33/installing-an-ssl-certificate-on-nginx/), may help to resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

**Try below steps to configure SSL certificates in NGINX web server:**

**1)Get SSL Certificate:**
You will get 3 files from the certificate authority via email or by logging into their website.

- key (e.g private.key) – your key file. Don’t share this with anyone publicly
- Certificate (e.g certificate.crt) – actual SSL/TLS certificate for your domain
- Intermediate (e.g intermediate.crt) – Root/intermediate certificate

**2)Link SSL Files:**
Create a directory to store the above-mentioned files

```
$ sudo mkdir /etc/nginx/ssl
$ cd /etc/nginx/ssl
```

Download the three SSL files mentioned in step 2 to the above directory. Link the certificate and intermediate files to create a bundle.crt file

```
cat certificate.crt intermediate.crt >> bundle.crt
```

**3)Open NGINX Configuration:**
Open terminal and run the following command to open NGINX server configuration file.

```
$ sudo vi /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

If you have configured separate virtual hosts for your website (e.g [www.example.com](http://www.example.com)), such as /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/example.conf then open its configuration with the following command

```
$ sudo vi /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/example.conf
```

***4)Configure SSL certificate in NGINX:**
Create a server block that listens to port 443 (HTTPS port)

```
server {
    listen 443;
    ssl on;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/bundle.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/private.key;
    ...
}
```

In the above configuration, the first line will ensure that NGINX server listens to port 443. The second line will enable SSL.
The next line specifies the SSL protocols to be supported by NGINX. For our example, we have enabled TLS version 1, version 1.1 and 1.2. You can change it as per your requirement.

The next two lines specify the file paths to bundle.crt file created in Step 2 and private.key downloaded in step 1. Here’s a sample server block for your reference

```
server {
    listen 443;
    ssl on;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/bundle.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/private.key;

    server_name www.example.com;
    access_log /path/to/nginx/accces/log/file;
    error_log /path/to/nginx/error/log/file;

    location / {
        root  /var/www/html/yoursite/;
        index  index.html;
    }
}
```

**5)Restart NGINX Server:**
Finally, run the following command to check syntax of your updated config file.

```
$ sudo nginx -t
```

If there are no errors, run the following command to restart NGINX server.

```
$ sudo service nginx reload #debian/ubuntu
$ systemctl restart nginx #redhat/centos
```

**6)Test NGINX SSL Configuration:**
Open a browser and visit https:// version of your domain (e.g https://www.example.com).
You will see a lock symbol next to your URL, in browser’s address bar, indicating that your website’s SSL/TLS certificate is working properly.

Hopefully, now you can configure SSL certificates in NGINX for Ubuntu as well as other Linux systems.